# NPM live-server configuration many 404 files

Tags: css, path, get, npx

> Hi, I have configured NPM live server with IP ADDRESS 192.168.100.53 on port 8080.
> However, after having started the live server with command npx live-server --host=192.168.100.53 --port=8080 --cors, some of the CSS files fail to load on the index page and the style of many elements are not loaded.
>
> The actual npx-live server configuration file contains these json and js code:
> const express = require("express");
> const cors = require("cors");
> const { Sequelize, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
> const liveServer = require("live-server");
> const path = require("path");
>
> const app = express();
>
> Middleware
> app.use(cors());
> app.use(express.static('public'));
> app.use(express.json());
>
> const liveServer = require("live-server");
> const path = require("path");
>
> Middleware was also configured for serving the css static files:
> const liveServer = require("live-server");
> const path = require("path");
>
> After having started the npx live-server inside the root directory, and navigating to the folder with the main website files, the chrome open up the browser with the website address and there is a 404 not found error message:
> Cannot GET /
>
> tasks.json configuration file contains these json lines:
>
> `{ "version": "2.0.0", "tasks": \[ { "type": "npm", "script": "start", "path": "server", "group": "build", "problemMatcher": \[\], "label": "npm: start - server", "detail": "Starting live-http server...", "options": { "env": { "LIVE_SERVER_HOST": "192.168.100.53", "LIVE_SERVER_PORT": "8080", "LIVE_SERVER_ROOT": "U:\\Plan_Afacere\\WebSite\\ComputerLaptop_WebSite" } } } \] }`
>
> What is wrong with this?
> the file paths are correct with the prefix in front of each of the style sheets inside the index.html page.
>
> example path:
>
> ```
> <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://192.168.100.53:8080/WebSite\public\acasa.css" type="css/text" media="all" method="GET">
> ```
>
> the prefix in front of the above href link address is: http://192.168.100.53:8080/ and followed by the relative path of the location of the CSS file: WebSite\public\acasa.css
>
> There are multiple other links which have the prefix put in front in order to be able to GET the files but the server does not load the files after the page finishes loading.
>
> Does anyone know what should the issue be and how should this be resolved?
>
> Also, the actual paths have been rechecked and do not contain any white spaces or empty spaces.
>
> Tried replacing the back slashes with forward slashes so the path would be readable by the web server. That did not function and the pages are still throwing a 404 response code.
>
> Also modified the package.json file to contain this information:
> "start": "live-server --open=home"
>
> {
> "name": "website",
> "version": "1.0.0",
> "description": "This is the main page for the website that I am building.\r *****************************\r *****************************\r Yet I am technically writing the lines of code while learning.\r *****************************\r *****************************\r The code files are being written.\r This is actually the main website for dropshipping.\r Products are actually imported from other producers.\r All pages are custom made.",
> "main": "index.js",
> "scripts": {
> "test": "echo "Error: no test specified" && exit 1",
> "start": "live-server --open=home"
> },
> "keywords": [],
> "author": "",
> "license": "ISC",
> "dependencies": {
> "bootstrap": "^5.3.2",
> "express": "^4.18.2",
> "pg": "^8.11.3",
> "sequelize": "^6.37.0"
> }
> }